# How does this group() catch the text?

Tags: java, regex

I've come across this Hackerrank problem and the regex should match string between the HTML tags. The regex and the string is

```
String str="<h1>Hello World!</h1>";
String regex="<(.+)>([^<]+)</\\1>";
```

Also what if the 'str' has more than one HTML tags like `String str="<h1><h1>Hello World!</h1></h1>"` and how `([^<]+)` catches this 'str'.

My question is how `([^<]+)` matches the 'str' and not `([a-zA-Z]+)`.

Here if the full source code :

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/* Solution assumes we can't have the symbol "<" as text between tags */
public class Solution{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int testCases = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());

        while (testCases-- > 0) {
            String line = scan.nextLine();

            boolean matchFound = false;
            Pattern r = Pattern.compile(regex);
            Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

            while (m.find()) {
                System.out.println(m.group(2));
                matchFound = true;
            }
            if ( ! matchFound) {
                System.out.println("None");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Don't mind if I'm stupid to ask this question and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex guarantees that your string only contains one tag, assuming well formed HTML input.

The initial `<(.+)>` captures the name of your tag. The capture group will also get any attributes it can. Since `+` is a greedy quantifier, it will capture multiple tags if it can.

The trailing `</\\1>` matches against whatever the first group captured. That's why, if your HTML is well formed, the expression won't capture multiple tags or tags with attributes:

- Opening tag `<h1>`, closing tag `</h1>` ✓
- Opening tag `<h1 attr="value">`, closing tag `</h1>`, but expecting `</h1 attr="value">`
- Opening tag `<h1><h2>`, closing tag `</h2></h1>`, but expecting `</h1><h2>`

That's why the tag can be matche with `.+` rather safely, while the contents must be matched with `[^<]+`. You want to make sure you don't grab any stay tags in the content, but any other character at all is allowed. `[^<]+` (pronounced. "not `<`, at least once) allows things like `!`, while `[A-za-z]` certainly would not.

Answer (score 2):

If the input string is `Hello World!` then `([a-zA-z]+)` will not properly match because of the exclamation point (!) and the space characters.

To be more clear, here is what each regex means:

- `([a-zA-Z]+)` Match a sequence (1 or more characters) that is made up of letters of the alphabet (upper or lower case)
- `([^<]+)` Match a sequence (1 or more characters) so long as a character **is not** a < character